# Using GPG keys generated with WSL in Windows directly?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnupg, gpg4win, kleopatra

So I'm just trying to sign my LibreOffice documents digitally. I have generated my GPG key in a Debian WSL terminal using the gpg command line. Yet when I access my LibreOffice documents, `File → Digital Signatures → Digital Signatures → Sign Documents`, the key generated isn't available (none is shown).

I also tried to import the key from the WSL to Windows with Kleopatra but when I click on `Import…` and try to import the `trustdb.gpg` file located in `/home/UserName/.gnupg/`, it doesn't import anything at all (imported : 0).

Maybe there is something I misunderstood. I'd like to know if it's possible to import a GPG key from WSL to be used in Windows directly or to use it directly from the WSL, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: trustdb doesn't contain keys, only metadata _about_ (some) keys. GPG keeps _other_ people's keys in pubring, but you can't sign using other people's keys because you are you and not someone else. Older versions of GPG kept your _own_ ('secret' or 'private' keys) in secring, but depending on what distro and other packages you are using usually they are now stored in a form that cannot be directly imported. Instead **first export them using `gpg [--armor] --export-secret-keys [ids...]`** to create an export file, and then import _that_.

Comment: So it really was something I misunderstood… Thank you, it worked. I'll make an answer and mark it solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [dave_thompson_085](https://superuser.com/questions/1613338/using-gpg-keys-generated-with-wsl-in-windows-directly/1613480#comment2460049_1613338) comment, I exported my key [`private.pgp`] from WSL, imported it into Kleopatra, and I was able to sign my LibreOffice documents:

```bsh
gpg --output private.pgp --export-secret-key user.name@email.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a quite hacky solution (but it works), if you're on WSL1 and have Gpg4Win installed (given you've already got Kleopatra): **leverage symbolic links**.

In WSL, run `ln -s /mnt/c/Users/(You)/.gnupg ~/.gnupg`.

Then create or import keys to your WSL environment as you would normally do.

Therefore WSL should share the same GPG profile as in your Windows environment.

Comment: This is not a good idea due to how ACLs are processed between Windows and WSL - just as with SSH keys, GPG keys must remain private and they will not be when linked across the two OS architectures _(e.g. WSL uses UGO, Windows uses ACLs and neither are compatible with the other)_, which creates a security risk when dealing with private keys. The correct way to do what you're suggesting would be to copy the WSL `~/.gnupg` directory to `%UserProfile%`